# Proving continuity: asking to see if I have a counter-example

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I was asked to prove the following:

> Suppose $F_1, \dots, F_2$ are disjoint closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.
>   Prove that if
>
> $$g: \cup_{k=1}^n F_k \to \mathbb{R}$$
>
> is a function such that $g_{|F_k}$ is a continuous function for each
>   $k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, then $g$ is a continuous function.

But I'm not sure if it's impossible. May I ask you to check if this is a counter-example?

$$A=\mathbb{N}$$
$$B=\{n+2^{−n}:n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$

and $g(x) = \lceil x \rceil$ (i.e. rounding up. For example, $g(3.0) = 3, g(3 + 2^{-3}) = 4$)

$g_{|A}$ and $g_{|B}$ are continuous, but $g$ is not.

Comment: What if you had disjoint closed sets $E_k$, such that $F_k \subset E_k$ but $E_k\not\subset F_k$, and $g$ is continuous on $D_k$ with $F_k \subset D_k \subset E_k$? That still satisfies continuity on $F_k$ but $g$ is not necessary continuous on $E_k$ and so not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $g$ is not continuous on $\mathbb R$ but it is continuous on $A \cup B$. So where is the contradiction? 
In fact $A \cup B$ is  a discrete space and any function on it is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
This exercise is Exercise 9 on p.72 in Exercises 2E in this book.

> Exercise 9
> Suppose $F_1,\dots,F_n$ are disjoint closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$ Prove that if $$g:F_1\cup\dots\cup F_n\to\mathbb{R}$$ is a function such that $g|_{F_k}$ is a continuous function for each $k\in\{1,\dots,n\},$ then $g$ is a continuous function.

And the author wrote as follows on p.66 in the book:

> Be careful about the interpretation of the conclusion of Luzin's Theorem that $f|_B$ is a continous function on $B$. This is not the same as saying that $f$ (on its original domain) is continuous at each point of $B.$ For example, $\chi_\mathbb{Q}$ is discontinuous at every point of $\mathbb{R}.$ However, $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}|_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}}$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ (because this function is identically $0$ on its domain).

$f:\mathbb{R}\ni x\mapsto\lceil x \rceil\in \mathbb{R}$ is not continuous at some point of $A\cup B$. ($f$ is discontinuos at every point of $A.$)
But $g=f|_{A\cup B}$ is a continuous function on $A\cup B.$

My solution for Exercise 9 is the following:

> Let $a$ be an arbitrary element of $F_1\cup\dots\cup F_n.$
> There exists an integer $k$ such that $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $a\in F_k.$
> Since $F_1,\dots,F_n$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R},$ $a\notin F_i$ for any $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{k\}.$
> Since $F_1,\dots,F_n$ are closed subsets of $\mathbb{R},$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{k\}$, there exists a positive real number $\delta_i$ such that $(a-\delta_i,a+\delta_i)\cap F_i=\emptyset.$
> Let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.
> Since $g|_{F_k}$ is a continous function, there exists a positive real number $\delta'$ such that $(a-\delta',a+\delta')\cap F_k\ni x\implies |g|_{F_k}(x)-g|_{F_k}(a)|<\epsilon.$
> Let $\delta:=\min(\{\delta_i:i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{k\}\}\cup\{\delta'\}).$
> Then, $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\cap (F_1\cup\dots\cup F_n)=(a-\delta,a+\delta)\cap F_k.$
> Then, $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\cap (F_1\cup\dots\cup F_n)\ni x\implies |g(x)-g(a)|=|g|_{F_k}(x)-g|_{F_k}(a)|<\epsilon.$
> So, $g$ is a continuous function.